# Horizontal Scrollbar for WPF ScrollViewer never displayed

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I am having trouble getting a Horizontal Scrollbar to be displayed for a WPF scroll viewer.  The `ScrollViewer` contains a User Control which dynamically renders its contents based on an input object so may be of variable size - when it renders itself it sets the Width and Height of the User Control to be the correct size.

I've set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to Visible which should force it to always be displayed but it is never displayed.  I have also tried playing with enabling/disabling `CanContentScroll` but it does not seem to make any difference.

Vertical Scroll Bars work fine without issue.

```
                ScrollViewer scroll = new ScrollViewer();
                scroll.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                scroll.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                scroll.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
                scroll.CanContentScroll = true;
                Grid.SetRow(scroll, 1);

                GalaxyViewer viewer = new GalaxyViewer(g);
                viewer.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                viewer.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                viewer.HideShips();
                viewer.IsEditable = this.IsEditable;
                viewer.GalaxyEdited += this._galaxyEditedHandler;
                if (this._activePlayer > 0 && !this.IsEditable) viewer.ShowShipsForPlayer(this._activePlayer);
                scroll.Content = viewer;
                ScrollViewer.SetCanContentScroll(viewer, true);
                ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(viewer, ScrollBarVisibility.Visible);

                scroll.UpdateLayout();
                grid.Children.Add(scroll);
```

Anyone have any ideas/solutions for this?

Comment: Interestingly the horizontal scrollbar appears only when I maximise the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem - the scroll bar was being displayed but I was automatically resizing the control containing the scoll viewer as the window was resized and this meant that the horizontal scoll bar was being clipped from the display

Comment: Could you describe your solution with more specifics? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 WPF Layout Controls - ScrollViewer
```

Most of the time,we don't know about the size of control ,which will be displayed in scree.
Also there is case of making product resolution dependent as this is basic property of wpf.
So That’s why in WPF there is a control i.e. ScrollViewer(Attached property) which can enable scrolling of those content whenever the content goes out to the display area.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.555,0.491">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>


Above example is a implementation of horizontal and vertical  scrollbar in a wpf form.
```

Automatic vertical scroll bar in WPF TextBlock?

For Detail Please Visit : http://wpfbugs.blogspot.in/2014/02/wpf-layout-controls-scrollviewer.html